# 2x2 Image Responsive Image Grid

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to make a grid of images in a 2x2 (horizontal x vertical) grid. When the screen is resized to a smaller size, I want these images to be displayed in a 1x4 vertical format, so that they retain most of their size. I've found several somewhat related articles from various websites, but they all have the content filling the entire page. This isn't something I want to do. The below image shows how the 2x2 grid should look. On the resized version of the site, it is perfectly okay for the images to fill the entire screen. How would I go about doing this?

I've now included a few screenshots of how I would like the final product to look roughly, but with images in place of the red squares. 
[e.g. desktop resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCNe0.gif) 
[e.g. smartphone resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK80d.gif)

```css
.imageLineTop {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 725px;
 top: 60%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

.imageLineBottom {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 45px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 725px;
 top: 60%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

#img0 {
 height: 700px;
}

#img1 {
 height: 700px;
}

#img2 {
 height: 700px;
}

#img3 {
 height: 700px;
}

#fadeBox0 {
 width: 478px;
 height: 700px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 left: 24%;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}

#fadeBox1 {
 width: 478px;
 height: 700px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 right: 24%;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}

#fadeBox2 {
 width: 478px;
 height: 700px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 left: 24%;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}

#fadeBox3 {
 width: 478px;
 height: 700px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 right: 24%;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
 <!--Top image line-->
  <section class="imageLineTop">
   <img class="discoverImage" id="img0" src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
   <img class="discoverImage" id="img1" src="assets/imgs/2.jpg">

   <section id="fadeBox0">
    <h3 class="imageInlineTitle">Purity.</h3>
   </section>

   <section id="fadeBox1">
    <h3 class="imageInlineTitle">Style.</h3>
   </section>
  </section>

  <!--Bottom image line-->
  <section class="imageLineBottom">
   <img class="discoverImage" id="img2" src="assets/imgs/3.jpg">
   <img class="discoverImage" id="img3" src="assets/imgs/4.jpg">

   <section id="fadeBox2">
    <h3 class="imageInlineTitle">Integrity.</h3>
   </section>


   <section id="fadeBox3">
    <h3 class="imageInlineTitle">Courage.</h3>
   </section>
  </section>
```

Comment: So just place this 2 images in parent div with some max-width and centre the parent div.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Sure thing, uploading it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what your end goal is here, but you can make your images go onto new lines once the window is smaller than their actual size by giving them:

```
.img0, .img1, .img2, .img3 {position: relative}
```

Remember not to use percentage width in this situation.

Please see the Fiddle below. Hopefully it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/7rtb084r/

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Since asking the question I had managed to work out something similar, but I'm still struggling as I also want the "grid" to be centrally positioned at all times. So when it is 2x2, the middle point between the two images in a row is at 50% of the screen width, and then when resized to 1x4, the middle of the image is at 50% of the screen width. Sorry if I'm not making myself clear, I'm just struggling to get me head around what I'm doing here, so don't know how to put my words to paper.

Comment: @Josh So for that you'd need to put the each row of images into a parent div, then add {margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; width: 1010px} to the parent. This is assuming that the images are 500px. See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rtb084r/4/

Comment: Thanks, yep, that gets me to where I want. If I combine the two fiddles however, it doesn't seem to work. They will perform correctly independent of each other, but when combined, they won't. Any tips on how to combine them would be greatly appreciated, so thank you in advance!

Comment: I've now also included a couple images in the main body of my post showing what it is exactly that I am ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @Josh Hi, Without seeing the exact code its difficult because media queries don't work on JsFiddle. But here is a Fiddle that shows what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/maL8pdtv/. You would then need to add a media query that said that when the screen was smaller than both images (around 1010px if your images are 500px) Then it should put them onto one line. Something like: '@'media only screen and (max-width: 1010px) {
.img1, .img2, .img3, .img4 {width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}
.contentTop, .contentBottom {width: auto}
}
Hopefully this helps. -remove '' around and symbol